# Check pregnancy

Tags: pregnancy

Is it true that instead of using a home pregnancy test you can you lay on your tummy and check for a pulse on your belly button? If you feel your own heartbeat, then you are not pregnant. Otherwise, you are pregnant.

Did someone lie to me or is there a scientific basis for this method?

Comment: This looks to me like a skeptics question:
http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pregnancy?page=2&sort=newest&pagesize=15

Comment: There are no household methods to check for pregnancy early on. The only way to check is to buy a test from a pharmacy or drugstore (you know, peeing on a strip of paper).

Comment: Zeina- if you are after answers, using that sort of language when you have just joined a community is not constructive.

Comment: @Zeina: Apologies for misreading. Same answers, no you cannot tell this way, even if you could, it would be far less reliable than a home pregnancy test and could be thrown off by any form of exercise or emotion that made your heart beat faster.

Answer (score 8):

No, that is not true. You can't feel the heartbeats through the bellybutton, and you can't feel anything, like kicks, etc, until way after it being obvious that you are pregnant anyway.

Answer (score 2):

You can't feel a heartbeat by pressing on your belly button even when the baby is ready to come out. It takes half of pregnancy for the baby to get bigger then your thumb.

Answer (score 1):

As Lennart says, you can't tell if you're pregnant that way.
Early signs of pregnancy can be mistaken for your period, or for a nasty infection ([nausea, tiredness, becoming moody](http://www.webmd.com/baby/guide/pregnancy-am-i-pregnant)).

If you aren't sure, take a pregnancy test when your next period is due, or see a doctor.